# Possibility to see what users type in the tags field

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think it would be very useful if a certain part of the usergroup with sufficient moderator tools could see what users type in their "tags" field when they ask questions.

There are often debates on meta sites about what exact tags there should be, how they should be named and whether they will even be used at all.

This tool would create an oppurtunity for those people to see what tags are needed, which I believe can be characterized by the fact that someone types a word until a certain length, and then backspaces it again. Then the job of the tool is to filter out the most hot non-tags such that the appropiate people can undertake action upon them.

Comment: I think it would be more flooded with useless tags that people type due to a misunderstanding of our system. It'd probably be 90% useless information.

Comment: @animuson I don't see an issue with sorting the data *at all*. It is not the bottom 90% that's useful, it is the top 10%.

Answer (score 5):

No, I don't want such feature. Common sense tells us that as long as we did not submit anything, it's not stored anywhere publicly. If I started typing a question or answer and never submitted it, I am certain it's not stored anywhere (except a draft which isn't accessible to anyone).

Tags should not be any different: users might type there just for fun, just to see how the auto complete works, etc. To take it to the extreme, user might paste something from the clipboard, which turns out to be sensitive/private information e.g. password.